# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python and am stuck with what to do right now because I keep getting this error.I am trying to change the following equation like:

`z = np.power(((float(X) * theta.T)-float(Y)), 2)`

but I can't seem to get it to work.

My code:

```
# convert from data frames to numpy matrices
X = np.matrix(x.values)  
Y = np.matrix(y.values)  
theta = np.matrix(np.array([0,0]))
# cost functionstrong text
def computeCost(X, Y, theta):
    z = np.power(((X * theta.T)-Y), 2)
    return np.sum(z) / (2 * len(X))
print('computeCost(X, y, theta) = ' , computeCost(X, Y, theta))
```

the matrix is full of float numbers:

```
 X = [[ 1.      6.1101] [ 1.      5.5277] [ 1.      8.5186] ...
```

The error message :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'
```

I appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks a lot

Comment: which line is causing this error?

Comment: line in computeCost
    z = np.power(((X * theta.T)-Y), 2)

Comment: you'll want to check the datatypes for `X` `theta` and `Y`, one of them seem to be `str` while you want them to be `float`

Comment: Thinks you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

do check datatypes of your dataframe

```
df.info()
```

if there's 'object' datatype, that's your string

you may want all datatypes in your dataframe as float, you can do it

```
df.astype('float')
```